# Bootstrap dropdown not appearing in IE9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Currently I'm wordpressing a site that is using Bootstrap, and the .dropdown-menu is not appearing in IE8 (and, more importantly, IE9).

From my readings I discovered that there is a filter in navbar that causes this issue. Probably is neither the .navbar or the .dropdown class contain the filter. And I'm not even using the class .navbar, just .dropdown & dropdown-menu.

I would love some input on how to fix this. I'm using SCSS:

```
 .header {
  height:90px;
  .brand {
    height: 90px;
    width: 246px;
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }

  nav {
    padding-top:36px;
    font-family:$tdSemibold;


    ul, li {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;

    }

    & > ul {
      & > li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left:40px;
        z-index: 9999;     

        & > a {
          color: white;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 16px;
          letter-spacing:1px;
          display:block;
          height:30px;

          & > span.caret {
            display: none;
          }

          &:hover {
            color: #85c1eb;
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #{darken(#85c1eb, 40%)};
          }

        }

        &.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
          background: #fff;
          z-index: 9999;
          display: inline-block;

        }
      }
    }



    .dropdown-menu {
        background: #fff !important;
      border-radius: 0;
      @include boxShadow(0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15));

      &:before {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        left: 5px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid white;
         z-index: 9999;
      }

      li {
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #eee;
        background: #fff;
          z-index: 9999;
        &:last-child {
          border-bottom: none;

        }
      }

      a {
        padding: 8px 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: $blue;

        &:hover {
          color:white;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```